# What can create threads in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the question about threads in ruby.
I'm supporting the site on RoR. When I looking threads in the command line, I see 3 threads ruby:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  755 deploy    20   0  395m 190m 3692 S   0.7  9.5   1:25.88 ruby                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
16703 deploy    20   0  339m 126m    0 S   0.0  6.3   0:01.91 ruby                                                                                                                                            
13415 deploy    20   0  272m 117m 1900 S   0.0  5.9   0:22.11 ruby
```

I don't use Sidekiq or something else, only site.
I don't create threads in my code.
Is it correct behaviour in my case?

Update. 
Result pstree:

```
init─┬─2*[postgres───8*[postgres]]
     ├─sshd───2*[bash───tail]
     ├─console-kit-dae───64*[{console-kit-dae}]
     ├─6*[getty]
     ├─java───40*[{java}]
     ├─2*[master─┬─pickup]
     │           ├─qmgr]
     │           ├─showq]
     │           └─tlsmgr]
     ├─2*[apache2─┬─PassengerAgent─┬─PassengerAgent───19* 
      [{PassengerAgent}]]
     │            │                ├─PassengerAgent───5* 
      [{PassengerAgent}]]
     │            │                └─5*[{PassengerAgent}]]
     │            └─10*[apache2]]
     ├─bash───tail
     ├─acpid
     ├─atd
     ├─cron
     ├─dbus-daemon
     ├─fail2ban-server───2*[{fail2ban-server}]
     ├─gam_server
     ├─mcelog
     ├─munin-node
     ├─mysqld_safe─┬─logger
     │             └─mysqld───18*[{mysqld}]
     ├─nrpe
     ├─ntpd
     ├─polkitd───{polkitd}
     ├─rpc.idmapd
     ├─rpc.statd
     ├─rpcbind
     ├─rsyslogd───3*[{rsyslogd}]
     ├─ruby───4*[{ruby}]
     ├─2*[ruby───3*[{ruby}]]
     ├─snmpd
     ├─sshd─┬─sshd───sshd───bash───pstree
     │      └─sshd───bash───tail
     ├─udevd───2*[udevd]
     └─vnstatd
```

Result pstree -up | less, part with ruby:

```
  ` |-ruby(755,deploy)-+-{ruby}(758)
    |                  |-{ruby}(759)
    |                  |-{ruby}(763)
    |                  `-{ruby}(764)
    |-ruby(13415,deploy)-+-{ruby}(13417)
    |                    |-{ruby}(13420)
    |                    `-{ruby}(13421)
    |-ruby(16703,deploy)-+-{ruby}(16706)
    |                    |-{ruby}(16708)
    |                    `-{ruby}(16709)`
```

Comment: What do you mean by sait?

Comment: I'm sorry, site of course

Comment: How do you run your app? Puma? Take a look at its config (workers/threads specifically)

Comment: No, I use WEBrick.

Comment: WEBrick is multi-threaded but Rails developers hard-coded a mutex, so it can handle just one request at a time

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/cff3941b817b976a57f42b374c3dfceff1ad459d/lib/webrick/server.rb#L185 each request is a new thread

Comment: WEBrick create a new thread for every user, who log in the site? I right understand?

Comment: a user can create many HTTP/ajax requests based on the application architecture. since each request creates a new thread, there can be multiple threads for a single user.

Comment: What output of `pstree`?

Comment: What you are listing are processes not threads.  You can have many threads per process.